# Can't find error in code JAVA

Tags: java

1. Write a method of type double called triangleArea which takes in two parameters of type double for the base and height of a triangle and returns the area.

Here is my code. On line **"triangleArea(height,base);"** an error message displays: 
**cannot find symbol 
symbol: variable height
location: class HWA

cannot find symbol
symbol: variable base
location: class HWA
Assign Return Value to New Variable

```
public class HWA {

public static void main(String[] args{  
    triangleArea(height,base);    
} 

public static double triangleArea(double height, double base){
 height = 12;
 base = 6;  
 double equal = (1/2)*(height*base);     
 return equal;    
     }  
}
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I fix it and still follow the requirements listed above?

Comment: Well, the variables `height` and `base` are not defined in your `main()` function. In addition, your `main()` function definition is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: suppose you code should be modified like below. public class HWA {

`public static void main(String[] args){  
    triangleArea(12,6);    
} 

public static double triangleArea(double height, double base){  
 double equal = (1/2)*(height*base);     
 return equal;    
     }  
}`

Comment: Yes, you need to add the closing parens on main, then you need to move height = 12 and base = 6 to the main method before the call to triangleArea. You'll need to change it to `double height = 12;` and `double base = 6;` when you do that. Also, you aren't doing anything with the return value of triangleArea. You need to assign it like `double area = triangleArea(height, base); Then I don't know print it. This code wont' do anything right now